# ipad missing overlapped annotations

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, annotations, drawing

While I'm trying to draw cross lines on iPad view , Its erasing the overlapped part of previous line. I'm using setNeedsDisplayInRect() method to refresh drawings. please suggest me to overcome this issue.

I wrote code for this is

I'm using the below code to draw:

```
context.MoveTo (penVertices [0].X, penVertices [0].Y);

for (int i = 1; i < penVertices.Count; i++) {

context.AddLineToPoint (penVertices [i].X, penVertices [i].Y);

}
context.StrokePath();
```

---

And using below code to display the line

```
SetNeedsDisplayInRect(RectangleF.FromLTRB(minX - (lineWidth/2), minY - (lineWidth/2), maxX + (lineWidth/2), maxY + (lineWidth/2)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi to avoid erasing of previous made annotations at overlapped place, Use paths to draw annotations instead of simple context.